# Is ASP.net MVC a direct copy of Ruby on Rails concepts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm been developing Ruby on Rails previously.  I'm now looking at an ASP.net web app and I'm looking at WebForms and MVC.  As I look at MVC it feels as if I'm looking at the result of something a Ruby on Rails developer implemented after being forced to work in MS land.  So I'm wondering:

Was MVC more or less taken directly from Ruby on Rails and it's concepts?  (either intentionally or unintentionally)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MVC has obviously existed long before Rails or ASP.NET MVC.

ASP.NET MVC is however, influenced by Ruby on Rails, but that really isn't a bad thing. Specification of routing is handled in a similar way, helpers are similar. While all MVC frameworks are similar, ASP.NET MVC feels as close to Rails as you could achieve in a language such as C#.

Comment: The MVC pattern isn’t new. it dates back to 1978 and the Smalltalk project at Xerox. Very Old-School :)

Answer (score 9):

I agree that the MVC pattern's been around a while and it's a good architecture for web apps, but if you look at ASP.NET MVC, you soon come to the conclusion that they could have named it Rails.NET

Answer (score 3):

I have worked with Struts, Spring, RoR and now asp.net MVC. I feel that there is enough room for different concepts, even if the main concept and brandname for a framework is MVC.

As it goes to asp.net MVC, it seems that RoR was taken as the reference implementation of web MVC.

Answer (score 2):

No, MVC is a design pattern that works very well for web applications. Ruby on Rails i think was an early adopter that showed how well suited it was for a web architecture, and was probably an influence on MS implementation, but did not come up with the design.

Comment: In other words, they both come from the same source.

Comment: RoR was definitely **not** an early adopter of MVC on web. For example Struts was available about 5 years before RoR.